# Question about sequences in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $S$ is compact, there are $x, y ∈ S$ so $|x − y| = d(S)$.

Where $ d(S)= \sup \{ \vec{x}-\vec{y}\}$
what i want to do is assume there is a sequence in S going to $\sup \{ \vec{x}-\vec{y}\}$ then use BW to choose a convergent sub-sequence of that sequence that converges to $x$ and a convergent sub-sequence of that sequence converging to y then since S compact this x, y are in S.

my concern is why can i say there a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ to then pick a sub-sequence and how do i justify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can ! :P

Since S is compact it is also bounded , hence $d(S)<\infty$.

Remember the characterisation of sup : if $A\subset \Bbb R$ an upper bounded subset of the reals then the

following preposition holds $\alpha = supA \iff \forall \epsilon >0 $ there exist $b \in A$ such that

$\alpha - \epsilon < b \leq a$ $\ (*)$.

Now $d(S)$ by definition is the $sup$ of the set $\{||x-y||:x,y \in S\}$. So you start

using the $(*)$ consecutively for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}>0$.

1)  for $\epsilon = 1>0$ there exist $x_1,y_1 \in S$ such that $d(S)-1 <||x_1 - y_1|| \leq d(S)$.

2) for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}>0$ there exist$x_2,y_2 \in S$ such that $d(S)-\frac{1}{2}<||x_2-y_2||\leq d(S)$.

So continuing with induction you can construct two sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ in $S$ such that

$d(S)-\frac{1}{n}<||x_n-y_n||\leq d(S)$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Now $||x_n-y_n||\to d(S)$.

Since S is compact you can find a subsequence of $x_n$ lets say $x_{k_{n}}\to x \in S$.

Now again from the compacteness of $S$ you find a subsequence of $y_{k_{n}}$ lets say $y_{k_{s_{n}}}\to y \in S$.

Now since $||x_n-y_n||\to d(S)$ you also have that

$||x_{k_{s_{n}}}-y_{k_{s_{n}}}||\to d(S)$  $(1)$ and $||x_{k_{s_{n}}}-y_{k_{s_{n}}}||\to ||x-y||$  $(2)$.

Combining $(1),(2)$ you get $||x-y||=d(S)$ and $x,y \in S$. I hope this is better!

Comment: sorry im not quite following you i was going to just going to say assume there was a sequence then by bolzano wierestrass theres a convergent sub sequence of that sequence that converges to x. are you saying you can do it differently?

Comment: Am trying to explain why you can say that there exist such a sequence.Two sequences to be more precise.I will edit the above so the argument would be more clear.

Comment: This is mostly correct in the sense that it will probably but not always work, i am very impressed you were able to construct the sequence but there is a small problem $d(S) -1 <0$ is possible in which case the $x_1,y_1$ pair that you picked could not be in S! ofc this is easy to fix but also introduces a trival case that must be dealt with separately and then theirs the empty set.

Comment: The subsequences $x_{k_{s_n}}$ and $y_{k_{s_n}}$ should have different indices. This gives rise to the issue that$ \|x_{k_n}-y_{j_n}\|$ might not satisfy $d(S)-1/2<\|x_{k_n}-y_{j_n}\|<d(S)$, as the original requirement implies this only holds for  $d(S)-1/i<\|x_{j}-y_{j}\|<d(S)$. So there's some extra work that needs to be done, for example by extracting a cauchy subsequence.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with your statement ... $x_n $ is a sequence which lies in the compact S, so we know that there exist a subsequence $x_{k_{n}}$ then i am forgetting the sequence $y_n$ and looking at the sequence $y_{k_{n}}$ which is also in S now from compactness there is a subsequence $y_{k_{s_{n}}}$ and the following inequality holds $d(S)-\frac{1}{k_{s_{n}}}<||x_{k_{s_{n}}}-y_{k_{s_{n}}}||\leq d(S$).